# Single sign on between domain and Wordpress in a subdirectory of domain

Tags: php, wordpress, session, single-sign-on, subdirectory

We have a private website at `www.domain.com` with its own users and user passwords. We are now adding a private WordPress site in a subdirectory `www.domain.com/store`. Since we already have a list of users on our main site, what is the best way to set up single sign on so that when a user logs into `www.domain.com`, they are automatically logged into `www.domain.com/store`?

All of the plugins we've found set up single sign on with a provider such as Google, Facebook, etc. which is not what we need.

This is the only way we've been able to do this so far:

1. Import existing users into `wp` database
2. When a user logs into `www.domain.com`, start a session in `wp` (this is done through a custom plugin we created)
3. When a user logs out of `wp` or `www.domain.com`, end the session in the other site so that the user is logged out of both sites.
4. Redirect visitors that are not logged in back to `www.domain.com` if they try to access any of the pages on the `wp` site.

In essence, we are creating two sessions (one on each site) for every successful login and destroying both sessions when they log out. This feels like the wrong way to do it but we don't know how else to set this up. Also, this method requires us to insert duplicate user data into the `wp` database whenever we create a new user in `www.domain.com`.

Comment: Essentially both systems need to use the same identity provider. Protocols such as OAuth2 are good for enabling this as you can likely find plugins / ready-made solutions for both the provider and the sites to enable it. (N.B. This is the same protocol that a lot of the "big" ID providers like MS, Facebook, Apple etc use).

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately, WordPress customizations make things much harder but here is my approach:

- you have 2 different domains the 2 of them should look into another endpoint let's call it "proxy.php"
- the proxy file is separated from the 2 projects, its only main goal is to set the session on the current user if it's not set
- the proxy should send you xyz token and this token you use as a validation key to enable the user to log in or not
- the proxy file should include a function to get_session($user_id) to list the user data

---

the idea is to have 1 shared file that manages the auth flow instead of managing all of them individually.